# Resource dll for exist library (localization)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, localization, resources, owin

There are MS library *Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll (package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.1.0)*

There are localization dll *ru/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.resources.dll (package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.ru.2.1.0)*

I want create Ukrainian localization dll *uk-UA/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.resources.dll*. I create project, add resource, build and copy to *uk-UA/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.resources.dll*. But it`s not work, Russian loaded Ukrainian not loaded.

In reflector dlls is:
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: uk is United Kingdom, by the way, not Ukraine.

Comment: Thanks, I change uk to uk-UA. Not loaded too